# Distance from circle to line segment: What is the intuition or geometry behind this algorithm?

Tags: geometry, vectors, algorithms, collision-detection

[I am using this algorithm](https://www.jeffreythompson.org/collision-detection/line-circle.php) to compute the distance between a circle and a line segment. I do not understand the part of the algorithm that involves dot products (and that kind of bothers me, I want to understand what I'm doing). To quote it in case the site ever goes down:

```
  // get length of the line
  float distX = x1 - x2;
  float distY = y1 - y2;
  float len = sqrt( (distX*distX) + (distY*distY) );

  // get dot product of the line and circle
  float dot = ( ((cx-x1)*(x2-x1)) + ((cy-y1)*(y2-y1)) ) / pow(len,2);

  // find the closest point on the line
  float closestX = x1 + (dot * (x2-x1));
  float closestY = y1 + (dot * (y2-y1));

  // is this point actually on the line segment?
  // if so keep going, but if not, return false
  boolean onSegment = linePoint(x1,y1,x2,y2, closestX,closestY);
  if (!onSegment) return false;
```

Where `x1, y1, x2, y2` are the coordinates defining the line segment, and `cx, cy` and `r` describe the circle's coordinates and radius.

Thank you. I'm not great at math (but not terrible) so emphasis on the intuition.

(side note: if there's an easier way to do this, let me know!)

Comment: Here's what I recommend. First find a way to find the shortest distance between a circle and a point (think about this geometrically), and work from there, noting that a line is just a collection of points, one after another.

Comment: I assume "pow(len,2)" means "length squared" in whatever language you are using?

Comment: Also, what exactly are you trying to find?  If I have a circle, and a line segment outside the circle, then okay, there is some point closest to the circle.  But what if the line segment is inside the circle, or partially inside?  What kind of answer do you want to get then?

Comment: Ouch! I'm not sure I would be taking programming advice from someone who calculates a number (len) as the *square root* of another calculation, and then the *only time* they make use of len, they *square* it (using the pow function, too - not just multiplying it by itself). Even with modern processors, taking of square roots and powers requires additional computational steps that are completely unnecessary here.

Comment: K.defaoite: Easy with Pythagoras and checking if the distance is smaller than the radius, but I don't know how to generalise that to line segments. RobertTheTutor: Yes, pow(len, 2) means length squared. This is a collision algorithm so it should return true if the circle and the line overlap, false otherwise. For my purposes, my circle is surrounded by a box of lines, and I check if it touches one of them. PaulSinclair: I didn't notice that! I'll use the website with a bit more scepticism.

Comment: Also, sorry if this comes off as a bit rude, but I really just wanted help visualising how this algorithm worked ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things needed here (after it has already been tested that the endpoints are outside the circle):

- The distance $d$ from the center $C$ of the circle to the line, and
- The location of the point $Q$ on the line which is closest to $C$.
  [image]

If $d > R$, then the line does not intersect the circle and we are done (if the line has no intersection, then neither does the line segment).

If $d \le R$, then the line does intersect the circle. But that doesn't mean the line segment intersects. It could be on a portion of the line away from the circle. For this we need $Q$, the point on the line closest to $C$. If $Q$ is between $P_1$ and $P_2$, then the segment intersects the circle.

If $P_1$ is between $Q$ and $P_2$, or vice versa, then the segment does not intersect the circle. We've already concluded that $P_1$ and $P_2$ are outside the circle. If there were a point of intersection between the segment and the circle, since $Q$ is inside the circle, everything between the intersection and $Q$ would also be inside the circle, including one of the two endpoints that we know are outside - a contradiction. So no such point of intersection can exist.

So the algorithm finds the coordinates of $Q$, calculates the distance $d$ to $C$, and checks to see if $Q$ is on the line segment $\overline{P_1P_2}$, all in a way that woefully inefficient. I've already pointed out the most glaring of the inefficiencies in a comment.

The key to finding $Q$ is that the line $\overline{CQ}$ is perpendicular to $\overline{P_1P_2}$. That is, it is the projection of $C$ onto the line. For reasons that [3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LyGKycYT2v0) can explain much better than I can, the dot product of the vector $\vec{P_1C}$ and the vector $\vec{P_1P_2}$ is (the length of the projected vector $\vec{P_1Q}$) multiplied by (the length $L$ of $\vec{P_1P_2}$).

The value `dot` in your algorithm is not the dot product itself, but the dot product divided by $L^2$ ($L$ is `len` in the algorithm). Dividing by $L$ once gives the length of $\vec{P_1Q}$, that is, the distance from $P_1$ to $Q$. Dividing by $L$ a second time gives the ratio of the distance $P_1Q$ to the distance $P_1P_2$:
$$\mathtt{dot} = \dfrac{P_1Q}{P_1P_2}$$
Once they know this ratio, they find $Q$ by the vector equation $$\vec Q = \vec P_1 + (\mathtt{dot})(\vec P_2 - \vec P_1)$$
which is the equation for the line through $P_1$ and $P_2$.

That explains their algorithm.

---

Now if you want a *good* algorithm, there are better ways to do it.

The direction of $\vec{CQ}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{P_1P_2}$. Because we are in a plane, there is only one direction (up to a change in sign) perpendicular to any nonzero vector. If $\vec{P_1P_2} = \begin{bmatrix} p_x\\p_y\end{bmatrix}$, then we are looking for a vector $\begin{bmatrix} n_x\\n_y\end{bmatrix}$ whose dot product with $\begin{bmatrix} p_x\\p_y\end{bmatrix}$ is $0$:
$$n_xp_x + n_yp_y = 0.$$ An easy trick for accomplishing this is just to set $n_x = p_y, n_y = -p_x$. This gives a vector $\vec n$ either parallel to $\vec{CQ}$ or anti-parallel (i.e., parallel to $\vec{QC}$). The length of $\vec n$ is the same as $\vec{P_1P_2}$, which is $L$.

Now instead of taking the dot product of $\vec{P_1C}$ with $\vec{P_1P_2}$, we take the dot product of $\vec{CP_1}$ with $\vec n$. Again per the interpretation of the dot product discussed in the 3Blue1Brown video, that dot product is going to be the length of the projection of $\vec{CP_1}$ onto the line of $\vec n$ times the length of $\vec n$, or its opposite. But the line of $\vec n$ is $\overline{CQ}$, so the projection is going to be $\vec{CQ}$ (because $\angle CQP_1$ is a right angle), and its length is just $d$, while the length of $\vec n$ is $L$:
$$\vec{CP_1} \cdot \vec n = \pm dL$$ so $$d^2 = \frac{(\vec{CP_1} \cdot \vec n)^2}{L^2}$$
The full line intersects the circle if and only if $d\le R$, or equivalently $d^2 \le R^2$ (no need to take square roots in this version).

Thus you do not need to know $Q$ in order to find $d$. However, you still need to know where $Q$ falls on the line through $P_1, P_2$. But all you need for that is `dot`. Another major inefficiency in their algorithm was calling a "linePoint" function which assuredly was written to test arbitrary points to see if they are on the line through $P_1, P_2$, to test if $Q$ is between $P_1$ and $P_2$. We already know that $Q$ is on the line, so most of the testing in that function is not necessary. And very likely, it tests for lying between $P_1$ and $P_2$ by recalculating the value of `dot`. For points $Q$ on the line, $0 \le \mathtt{dot} \le 1$ when $Q$ is between $P_1$ and $P_2$. (It is $< 0$ when $Q$ is on the other side of $P_1$ and $>1$ when $Q$ is on the other side of $P_2$, this follows from `dot` being the ratio of $P_1Q$ to $L$, where $P_1Q$ is negative when $Q$ is outside of $P_1$.)

This gives a nicer algorithm:

```
boolean IsCollisionCircleLine(float cx, float cy, float r, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
    // Change coordinate origin to be at the circle center
    x1 = x1 - cx
    y1 = y1 - cy
    x2 = x2 - cx
    y2 = y2 - cy

    // Square the radius to avoid needing any square roots
    float r2 = r * r
    
    // Check if endpoints are in the circle
    if (x1 * x1 + y1 * y1 <= r2) return true
    if (x2 * x2 + y2 * y2 <= r2) return true
   
    // Calculate the line segment length squared
    float len2 = (x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2)*(y1 - y2)

    // find the perpendicular vector to the line segment
    float nx = y2 - y1
    float ny = x1 - x2

    // find the distance squared from center to line, times len2
    float dist2 = nx * x1 + ny * y1
    dist2 = dist2 * dist2

    // Check if full line intersects the circle. If not, return false
    if (dist2 > len2 * r2) return false

    // Calculate the distance from (x1,y1) to the point of closest approach) times the segment length
    float index = (x1*(x1 - x2) + y1*(y1 - y2)) 

    // Check if point of closest approach is inside the segment.
    if (index < 0) return false
    if (index > len2) return false
    return true
```